# Let users upload image(s) to the post from front end

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-field, attachments

I want to enable logged in users (Wordpress) to submit posts from front end (among with other data).

My form is working great, I add custom post meta data which I later display on custom post page.

I added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to form tag.

Added this code to functions.php:

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

And this to the custom post page (where the front end form is):

```
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
    }
};
```

After this php code I have this code to create post:

```
$post_information = array(
'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['title']),
'post_content' => $_POST['content'],
'post_category' => array($_POST['category']),
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'pending'
);

$post_information = wp_insert_post($post_information);
add_post_meta($post_information, 'custom1', $_POST['custom1']);
add_post_meta($post_information, 'custom2', $_POST['custom2']);
add_post_meta($post_information, 'custom3', $_POST['custom3']);
```

Now the post data is added to the new post without problems, and the image is uploaded.
I upload image with this:

```
<input type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload1" id="custom-upload2" />
<input type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload2" id="custom-upload2" />
<input type="file" tabindex="3" name="custom-upload3" id="custom-upload3" />
```

Now I need to find a way to save and show image on the created custom post. I was thinking about this two options:

1. Save the uploaded image URL in a custom field.
2. Save image directly to the post.

For my case the first option would be better, but I do not know how to do this.

Is there any way to save like that:

```
add_post_meta($post_information, 'imageURL', $_POST['imageURL']);
```

But i do not know how to pass the image URL variable to 'imageURL'.

Is there any option to do that?

Comment: There's a logical issue in the first codeblock: `__return_false();` will give you the value `FALSE` right there, but it does not return anything back out of `insert_attachment`.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_insert_attachment` returns the resulting `post_ID` of attachment record created in posts table, so you will need to add these IDs (multiple) in the post meta table using `update_post_meta` as suggested in code below:

```
$attchmentIds = array();
if ($_FILES) {
    foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
        $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$pid);
        $attchmentIds[] = $newupload;
    }
};
/*The following code will go after wp_insert_post call*/
update_post_meta($post_information, '_post_custom_attachments', $attchmentIds);
```

Now once this is done, when you want to display images on posts single page, you will need to get these attachment IDs from the post meta field and use `wp_get_attachment_url` function:

```
/*The_Loop*/
$attachmentIds = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_post_custom_attachments');

foreach($attachmentIds as $attachmentId) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachmentId );
    //outputs something like http://example.net/wp-content/uploads/filename
}
```

Reference Links:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url